# Labelling and drawing at rotated/shifted objects

Tags: tikz-pgf, arrows, labels

I'm trying to draw an image from [a mathematical publication](http://www.springerlink.com/content/25a0ynyrrw2gbwly/) (see the crop at the end of my post). You can find a recent version of the drawing at page 37 of [my script (PDF)](https://web.archive.org/web/20151105041802/http://uni-skripte.lug-jena.de/richter-geozerl.pdf). The complete source is [here](http://svn.lug-jena.de/richter-geozerl/skript.ltx?root=uni-skripte&revision=HEAD&content-type=text%2Fplain).

I drew a rhomb with those squares in it and shifted all pieces to the right place:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) -- (4,1) -- (8,0) -- (4,-1) -- (0,0);
\draw[thick] (6,.5) -- (4,1) -- (4,-1) -- (6,-.5)
  [yshift=4cm]  (6,.5) -- (4,1) -- (4,-1) -- (6,-.5);
\draw[thick,dashed] (6,.5) -- (6,-.5)
  [yshift=4cm]  (6,.5) -- (6,-.5);
```

I did the same with the squares around those figures. Now I want to label each square (R_0, R_1) and draw arrows from one box to another.

I'm looking for a better way than to write something like `\draw[->] (2,2) -- (2,0);`. So adding nodes sounds like the right idea, but I found no working solution. What would you recommend for drawing arrows and adding some  labels?

[image: crop of a drawing]

Comment: The link to the paper at `springerlink.com` is broken. I'm also unable to find a copy saved on the Wayback Machine. The link to the complete source appears to be broken, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the shapes tikz-library. I am including an example, but you should read *section 48.3 Geometric shapes* on *page 420* from the tikz manual. Here is the example

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\node[draw=lightgray,rectangle,inner sep=0.5cm,outer sep=5pt,label=245:$R_0$] (top) {\tikz{
    \node[draw,trapezium,trapezium angle=75,shape border rotate=270,outer sep=0pt] (top trap)
        {$\sigma(S_0)$};
    \draw[white,postaction={draw=black,dashed}]
        (top trap.bottom left corner) -- (top trap.bottom right corner);    
        }};

\node[draw=lightgray,rectangle,inner sep=0.5cm,below=2cm of top,outer sep=5pt,label=245:$R_0$] (bottom) {\tikz{
    \node[draw,trapezium,trapezium angle=75,shape border rotate=270,outer sep=0pt] (trap)
        {$T_0$};
    \draw[white,postaction={draw=black,dashed}] (trap.top left corner) -- (trap.top right corner);  
        }};


\draw[->] (top) -- (bottom) node[pos=0.5,right] {$\varphi|_{R_0}$};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The result is

[image]